# How to update only the queried objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a table `ActivityLog` to which new data is added in every second.
I am querying this table every 5 seconds using an Api in the following way.

```
 logs = ActivityLog.objects.prefetch_related('activity').filter(login=login_obj,read_status=0)
```

Now let's say when I queried this table at time 13:20:05 I've got 5 objects in `logs` and after my querying 5 more rows were added to the table at 13:20:06. When I try to update only the queried `logs`dataset using `logs.update(read_status=1)` it also updates the newly added data in the table. That is instead of updating 5 objects it updates 10 objects. How can I update only the 5 objects that I've queried without looping through it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update). Just be aware that the rows will be locked in the meanwhile.

Comment: I need to evaluate the queryset. This method blocks the queryset from evaluating. When I provide `select_for_update(skip_locked=True)`  to allow evaluation it throws an error like `select_for_update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_locked'`

Comment: skip_locked only came in Django 1.11. Are you on a version lower than that?